# mysql stored proc truncate table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, truncate

Here is the 'backstory': I have a mysql stored proc that ends up creating tables and then it should destroy the tables at the end of the proc.  The reason I'm doing this is because I want to make sure that if the proc fails that I don't end up stacking up these "temp" tables that I'm creating (they really aren't temp tables but I just call them that because they are supposed to be deleted when I'm done in the proc).  Anyway, the first 20 or so lines of my proc are below.

```
-- build dynamic sql to drop any tables that have been around for longer than 30 seconds

SELECT CONCAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ',GROUP_CONCAT(TableName),';')
INTO @dropcmd FROM TempTableTracker WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, Created, NOW()) > 30; 

-- execute dynamic sql
PREPARE dropcmd FROM @dropcmd;
EXECUTE dropcmd;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE dropcmd;

DELETE FROM TempTableTracker WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, Created, NOW()) > 30; 

SET @nextOutTable = concat('Insert into TempTableTracker (Created, TableName) values (NOW(),''',tableName,''')');
PREPARE nextOutTable FROM @nextOutTable;
EXECUTE nextOutTable;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE nextOutTable;
```

**The proc is currently throwing an error that says 
"Not unique table/alias: 'HelperTable088747200147510875390'"
If I comment out the following piece of code then the proc works**

```
PREPARE dropcmd FROM @dropcmd;
EXECUTE dropcmd;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE dropcmd;
```

Doesn't really make much sense to me.  If I run that code that I commented out 'manually' (plus the select concat statement ... not in a proc) from my sql editor then it also works.  Any ideas about what may be going on here ?

Here is the whole proc ->

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE "usergroupCalcs"( IN sqlstatement TEXT, IN tableName      VARCHAR(1000), IN topLevelParentID INT)
BEGIN

-- build dynamic sql (DROP TABLE tbl1, tbl2...;)
SELECT CONCAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ',GROUP_CONCAT(TableName),';')
INTO @dropcmd FROM TempTableTracker WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, Created, NOW()) > 30; 

-- execute dynamic sql
PREPARE dropcmd FROM @dropcmd;
EXECUTE dropcmd;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE dropcmd;

DELETE FROM TempTableTracker WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, Created, NOW()) > 30; 

SET @nextOutTable = concat('Insert into TempTableTracker (Created, TableName)     values (NOW(),''',tableName,''')');
PREPARE nextOutTable FROM @nextOutTable;
EXECUTE nextOutTable;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE nextOutTable;



SET @dropTable = concat('Drop table if exists ',tableName);
PREPARE dropTable FROM @dropTable;
EXECUTE dropTable;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE dropTable;



SET @createTable = concat('CREATE TABLE ',tableName,' (usergroupID INT, storeID INT, parentID INT, INDEX ug (`usergroupID`), INDEX st (`storeID`), INDEX pim (`parentID`)) ENGINE=MEMORY');
PREPARE createTable FROM @createTable;
EXECUTE createTable;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE createTable;




SET @insertIntoTable = concat('INSERT INTO ',tableName, ' ',sqlstatement );
PREPARE insertIntoTable FROM @insertIntoTable;
EXECUTE insertIntoTable;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE insertIntoTable;


SET @repeatStatement = concat('DELETE entry.* FROM ',tableName,' entry LEFT JOIN ',tableName,' parent ON entry.parentID = parent.usergroupID AND entry.storeID = parent.storeID WHERE parent.usergroupID IS NULL AND entry.parentID NOT IN ( ',topLevelParentID,' )');
PREPARE repeatStatement FROM @repeatStatement;

  REPEAT
    EXECUTE repeatStatement;
  UNTIL row_count() = 0 END REPEAT;  

  DEALLOCATE PREPARE repeatStatement;

SET @dropTempTable = concat('DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS ',tableName,'_out');
PREPARE dropTempTable FROM @dropTempTable;
EXECUTE dropTempTable;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE dropTempTable;


SET @createTempTable = concat('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ',tableName,'_out (usergroupID INT, storeID INT, parentID INT, INDEX ug (`usergroupID`), INDEX st (`storeID`), INDEX pim (`parentID`)) ENGINE=MEMORY COLLATE ''utf8_general_ci'' as select * from ',tableName);
PREPARE createTempTable FROM @createTempTable;
EXECUTE createTempTable;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE createTempTable;


SET @dropTempTableTwo = concat('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ',tableName);
PREPARE dropTempTableTwo FROM @dropTempTableTwo;
EXECUTE dropTempTableTwo;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE dropTempTableTwo;


END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`. They're dropped automatically when you close the database connection.

Comment: `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` generates a warning for any tables that don't exist. It sounds like something is turning the warning into an error.

Comment: Show how you are calling the stored proc and show the create proc line. And of course the stuff you rem out makes it work fine since that is the part that executes the string. And if you want me to know you are wanting me to fix it, do a "hey @drew there is the edit" ... do an [edit]

Comment: Does the table name appear more than once in `@dropcmd`?  You can `SELECT @dropcmd;` to inspect the value after the error occurs -- it will still be in scope.

Comment: I'm not using CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE because I have to self join to the table multiple times and that isn't allowed with a temporary table.  There is one workaround that I know of and that involves duplicating the temp table for each self join.  

I'm gonna check out that warning possibility Barmar.  

I have inspected the @dropcmd var and it looks correct to me.

Comment: I figured it out.. Stupid stupid.  I have a var named tableName and I was also referencing a column named TableName in the delete statement.  It was substituting the passed in tablename var for the column in the group_concat statement and that is why it was failing.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.. Stupid stupid. I have a var named tableName and I was also referencing a column named TableName in the delete statement. It was substituting the passed in tablename var for the column in the group_concat statement and that is why it was failing.